# Is there a version of Process Monitor that runs on Windows 2000?

Tags: windows, sysinternals, process-monitoring, procmon

I have a problem I'm trying to track down on a Windows 2000 machine.  I downloaded SysInternals Process Monitor (ProcMon.exe) but it seems to need Windows XP SP2 or higher.

I've seen traffic that suggested it once worked with Windows 2000 SP4. Any idea where I could get hold of that version?

Comment: What type pf problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd refer you to this thread on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/129044/where-to-get-working-sysinternals-tools-for-windows-2000) - they have a link to a mirror of an older sysinternals site. They also seem to indicate the older filemon/regmon worked better than procmon on win2k.

Answer (score 2):

The oldest version I can find is 10.2.

From the enclosed help file:

> Process Explorer does not require administrative privileges to run and works on Windows 9x/Me, Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Server 2003 and on the x64 version of 64-bit Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

[Uploaded to Media Fire](http://www.mediafire.com/?wk45h867vkknpuo)

Comment: That's Process **Explorer**. We're after Process **Monitor**.

Comment: Wow, the link still works!